# plot function in Julia won't process data taken from datasets

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, plot, julia

The 2-d array being created on using reading the dataset is of type any. Here is my code:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
using DelimitedFiles
import Base: convert, promote_rule
fi=readdlm("train.csv",',')
att1=fi[:,1]
att2=fi[:,3]
plot(att1,att2)
```

This is the error message

```
No user recipe defined for SubString{String}

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] convertToAnyVector(::SubString{String}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/series.jl:14
 [3] convertToAnyVector(::Array{Any,1}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/series.jl:65
 [4] macro expansion at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/series.jl:138 [inlined]
 [5] apply_recipe(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Type{Plots.SliceIt}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Nothing) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/RecipesBase/Uz5AO/src/RecipesBase.jl:275
 [6] _process_userrecipes(::Plots.Plot{Plots.PyPlotBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{Array{Any,1},Array{Any,1}}) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/pipeline.jl:83
 [7] _plot!(::Plots.Plot{Plots.PyPlotBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{Array{Any,1},Array{Any,1}}) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/plot.jl:178
 [8] #plot#132(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,1},N} where N) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/plot.jl:57
 [9] plot(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1}) at /home/jrun/.julia/packages/Plots/rmogG/src/plot.jl:51
 [10] top-level scope at In[75]:8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact, that your input is a container of type `Any` shouldn't matter much. See this example which works just fine:

```
julia> using Plots

julia> x = rand(3);

julia> xany = Any[x...];

julia> typeof(x)
Array{Float64,1}

julia> typeof(xany)
Array{Any,1}

julia> plot(x,x) # works

julia> plot(xany,xany) # works as well
```

So it seems to me that the actual content of your `Array{Any, 1}` isn't processable. From the error message I would guess that it contains strings (or substrings) instead of numbers. If this is the case, try to convert these strings to numbers first.

Reproducing the (similar) error

```
julia> xanystrings = Any[string.(x)...]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 "0.22161258086701574"
 "0.8190303081538728"
 "0.3519207194248777"

julia> plot(xanystrings, xanystrings)
ERROR: No user recipe defined for String
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] convertToAnyVector(::String, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\series.jl:14
 [3] convertToAnyVector(::Array{Any,1}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\series.jl:65
 [4] macro expansion at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\series.jl:138 [inlined]
 [5] apply_recipe(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Type{Plots.SliceIt}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Nothing) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\RecipesBase\Uz5AO\src\RecipesBase.jl:275
 [6] _process_userrecipes(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{Array{Any,1},Array{Any,1}}) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\pipeline.jl:83
 [7] _plot!(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{Array{Any,1},Array{Any,1}}) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\plot.jl:178
 [8] #plot#132(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,1},N} where N) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\plot.jl:57
 [9] plot(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1}) at C:\Users\carsten\.julia\packages\Plots\qh1wV\src\plot.jl:51
 [10] top-level scope at none:0
```

Fixing it:

```
julia> xfixed = parse.(Float64, xanystrings)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.22161258086701574
 0.8190303081538728
 0.3519207194248777

julia> plot(xfixed, xfixed) # works again
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, the header of my dataset was being taken into the array. So it had Strings. As a result, I couldn't even parse it. But this helped me to debug. Working fine now, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Since you seem to be new to stackoverflow let me point out that if you consider my answer to be satisfying, you might want to mark it as the accepted answer. This way both you and the answerer get some credit and it will indicate to others that this question is solved.